# Pre-processing data within a Julia structure

Tags: python, class, data-structures, struct, julia

I would like to have a Julia structure with data and parameters contained with it, to be used with various functions. E.g., I start with data frame of numbers, but many functions use it as a matrix and also need to know its dimensions. In python I would use something like:

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self, df):
        X = df.to_numpy()
        self.n, self.m = X.shape
        row_names = df.index.tolist()
        col_names = df.columns.tolist()

Foo = my_class(df)
```

What poses a difficulty is whether operations `.to_numpy()`, `.shape`, etc. can be performed in the Julia structure or whether beforehand. Or perhaps this necessitates using a mutable structure?

At my current level of knowledge I would do something like this:

```
struct MyClass
    df::DataFrame
    X::Matrix{Float64}
    n::Int64
    m::Int64
    row_names::Vector{String}
    col_names::Vector{String}
end

X = Matrix{Float64}(df[:,begin+1:end])
n, m = size(X)
row_names = df[:,begin]
col_names = names(SAT[:,begin+1:end])

Foo = MyClass(df, X, n, m, row_names, col_names)
```

Remark: thinking of it, I could probably wrap the code above in a function, which returns the initialized structure Foo. But it seems like a convoluted way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

After asking this question on [Julia site](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pre-processing-data-within-a-julia-structure/109979/2) and looking through the suggested reading on Julia [constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/), I think the answer should be the following:

```
struct MyClass
    df::DataFrame
    X::Matrix{Float64}
    n::Int64
    m::Int64
    row_names::Vector{String}
    col_names::Vector{String}
    function MyClass(df::DataFrame)
        X = Matrix{Float64}(df[:,begin+1:end])
        n, m = size(X)
        row_names = df[:,begin]
        col_names = names(SAT[:,begin+1:end])
        new(df, X, n, m, row_names, col_names)
    end
end

Foo = MyClass(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will enjoy more writing this code when you try `using Parameters` package.

```
@with_kw struct MyClass
    df::DataFrame
    X::Matrix{Float64} = Matrix{Float64}(df)
    n::Int64 = nrow(df)
    m::Int64 = ncol(df)
    col_names::Vector{String} = names(df)
end
```

I believe this is much more elegant code!

Now you can do:

```
julia> MyClass(;df=DataFrame(;x=1:5,y=rand(5)))
MyClass
  df: DataFrame
  X: Array{Float64}((5, 2)) [1.0 0.7209562166867965; 2.0 0.631191235109081; … ; 4.0 0.6223966407761956; 5.0 0.7149361412777603]
  n: Int64 5
  m: Int64 2
  col_names: Array{String}((2,))
```

There is also an inbuilt `@kwdef` macro (just replace in the above code `@with_kw` with `@kwdef` to find out). However `Parameters` provides nicer formatting when displaying `struct`s so personally I like it more.

(I omitted `begin+1` etc. which is specific to your use case - you can add it of course)